# Mysql ranking system

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to display a ranking table in a game based on player score like this

```
SELECT name, score FROM players ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT x, 30;
```

Where x is the rank to display from.

This turns out to be too slow taking 0.1 sec and often longer to execute. Any other solutions?

Comment: Can you post an EXPLAIN, to check it really is using the index?

Answer (score 1):

Create Index on score column using:
CREATE INDEX `score` ON `players` (`score`);